# Wrong application instance from ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext

Tags: android, robolectric, androidx-test

I am providing my own implementation of `Application` by creating a subclass and specifying the fully-qualified name of this subclass as the `android:name` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml`'s `<application>` tag as:

```xml
<application
        android:name=".GeniuzApp"
...
```

Running this Android App I can get the correct `Application` object in an `Activity` such as: `val app = application as GeniuzApp`

Yet, when I call `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext` in a unit test, which is configured with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`, I am not getting an instance of my `Application` subclass (i.e. `GeniuzApp`).

Do I need to provide anything else on my unit test to get the correct application instance?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the following in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests {
      includeAndroidResources = true
    }
  }
}
```

as stated in [Building with Android Studio/Gradle](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/#building-with-android-studiogradle)